# Looping and creating an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Trying to port some old PHP code to Ruby and missing some key info on creating arrays in Ruby.

The PHP code:

```
foreach ($results as $r) {
    $array[$r['column']][] = $r
}
```

Is this the simplest way to do it in Ruby? Do I have to initialize the second array?

```
@array = []
result.each do |r|
  @array[r.cron_column] = []
  @array[r.cron_column] << r
end
```

I figure this is a simple syntax issue, but my Googling has turned up empty.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are these arrays or hashes, or hashes of arrays? What is `r.column`, and what is the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indexing into an empty array, so that will always return nil.  nil does not define the << operator, so you get an error.  You need to initialize the value at array[index] if you want to use the << operator.

I am assuming you want an array of arrays, so you can use this instead which will initialize the value at items[index] to an empty array if it is nil before pushing the value onto it

```
items = []
array.each do |r|
  (items[r.column] ||= []) << r
end
```

The only change here is that, if items[r.column] returns nil it will be set equal to an empty array, otherwise nothing will be done. If you really just want to set the value at items[index] to r, just use the = operator.

Comment: Thanks Ed!  I figured there was a shorter way to do it.

Comment: No problem.  It is not equivalent to your sample code though.  Your snippet will wipe out the current value at items[r.column] each time, while mine will initialize only if it is nil and then append the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
array = results.inject([]) { |m, r| m[r.column] = r; m }
```

*Update*: oh, `e1[] = e2` adds a new array element in PHP, so [tokland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188031/tokland) is right, in which case:

```
array = results.inject([]) { |m, r| (m[r.column] ||= []) << r; m }
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to accumulate values in an array, not just override with the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need an array as output? it would appear a hash would be more convenient;  moreover, it's way easier to build in your scenario (which is usually a sign you are in the correct path):

```
# example
results = [
  OpenStruct.new(:x => 1, :cron_column => 0), 
  OpenStruct.new(:x => 2, :cron_column => 1), 
  OpenStruct.new(:x => 3, :cron_column => 1),
] 

@array = results.group_by(&:cron_column)
# {0=>[#<OpenStruct x=1, cron_column=0>], 
#  1=>[#<OpenStruct x=2, cron_column=1>, #<OpenStruct x=3, cron_column=1>]}
```

If cron_column "has no holes" (that's it, you have values from 0 to N), you can easily create an array with this same idea: `results.group_by(&:cron_column).sort.map { |k, v| v }` or `results.group_by(&:cron_column).sort.map(&:last)`, as you prefer.